# How to map SQL Server text column with Entity Framework Core 2.0 Model property

Tags: sql, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am using Entity Framework Core 2.0 and SQL Server 2016. I have a .cs class model that maps the SQL Server tables. I am able to insert long string in SQL Server text column, but I am not able to get that column with this model, it returns null with an error:

> Object reference object reference not set to instance of object

Model property that holds data is type of string. Any ideas how to map a SQL Server text column with Entity Framework Core 2.0?

Comment: `ntext`, `text`, and `image` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)`, and `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I changed my text field to nvarchar(max). Now I am also able to insert data, but when getting it says 'Object reference object reference not set to instance of object', it returns null, but data is inserted properly.

Comment: Please prepare a short, complete repro of your issue.  You'll probably find the problem when you do.  If not, post it in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Blog>(eb =>
    {
        eb.Property(b => b.Url).HasColumnType("ntext");
        eb.Property(b => b.ModernUrl).HasColumnType("nvarchar(MAX)");
    });
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relational/data-types